# JavaScript design pattern, a function is being overwritten

Tags: javascript, jquery

Code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/nNdna/
live page is here: http://www.sumsy.com/demos/socialFeeds/

Please go to the live page and check you debugger. You should see "pinterest init" shows up in the log. But I was expecting "twitter init" to be show up in the log, because I was calling Twitter.init from the main function.

MY setup was:
there are 2 Anonymous self executing functions, both having init function inside

```
var Twitter = (function($, window){ ... init = function ... 
var Pinterest = (function($, window){ ... init = function ...
```

then from my main function, I called Twitter.init(user_twitter_options);

But it seems like Pinterest.init is actually being called.
It looks like Pinterest.init overwritten Twitter.init function.

Can anyone please tell me what is wrong? I should not have 2 Anonymous self executing functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lots of issues with the code in the fiddle.

Both `Twitter` and `Pinterest` are being assigned to the result of calling anonymous functions that return `this` where `this` will be equal to `window` because you aren't actually creating new objects with `new` or otherwise doing anything to set `this` to something.

Within both anonymous functions you assign `init = ...` without declaring it with `var` which means `init` will be a global variable. So the code within the `Pinterest` section will overwrite the global `init` originally created within the `Twitter` section.

Given that globals are essentially properties of the `window` object and `Twitter` and `Pinterest` are both assigned to `window` that means that calling both `Twitter.init()` and `Pinterest.init()` is the same as calling `window.init()`. So that's why they both do the same thing.

Unfortunately your code is too long for me to go through to provide a working version, so I suggest you read some or all of these references:

- [Working with objects - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)
- [JavaScript Module Pattern In Depth - Adequately Good](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth/)
- [JavaScript Closures and the Module Pattern](http://www.joezimjs.com/javascript/javascript-closures-and-the-module-pattern/)
- [A Variation of JavaScript Module Pattern](http://web20boom.com/web/blog/?a=1)

Answer (score 1):

you need to add `var` in front of `init`, otherwise you are putting it in the global scope. This means that init will be equal to last assignment, which in this case is the Pinterest version.

Comment: but if i add var to init. it would give me an error Twitter.init is not a function, when i call Twitter.init(user_twitter_options); from main function

Comment: if i do this.init to both Twitter and Pinterest, the same issue there. the pinterest init is being called. i think this add them to global again? maybe i am wrong

Comment: Using `this.init` would be heading in the right direction, but it wouldn't fix the problem because the way both anonymous functions are called results in `this` being `window` within both.